# C# - SQL Insert Value and ID of checkbox From CheckboxList

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox, checkboxlist

**The Issue:**

I populate a checkbox list from a SQL table:

```
public static List<string> populateCheckBoxes(string type)
        {
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            items.Add("");

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlcmd;
            switch (type)
            {
                case "referralorsignposting":
                    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SWApp_List_Equipment WHERE type = 'Referral or Signposting' ORDER BY order_no, name", conn);
                    break;
                case "actionstaken":
                    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SWApp_List_Equipment WHERE type = 'Actions Taken' ORDER BY order_no, name", conn);
                    break;
                default:
                    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SWApp_List_Equipment", conn);
                    break;
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                items.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
                CheckboxIDRecord = dr["id"].ToString();
                //items.Add(dr["VisitTime"] + " " + dr["PropPostcode"]);
            }

            return items;
        }
```

I have iterated through each value that is selected in the "checkboxlist" and this  inserts each value selected:

```
foreach (var item in saw.actionsTakenCheckBoxList)
                {   //ADD ACTIONS AND REFERRAL 
                    SqlCommand add = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SWApp_CheckboxAnswers (SW_ID, Checkbox_ID, Checkbox_Section, Checkbox_Type, Checkbox_Answer) VALUES(@SW_ID,@Checkbox_ID,@Checkbox_Section,@Checkbox_Type,@Checkbox_Answer) ");
                    add.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    add.Connection = sqlcon;
                    add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SW_ID", "");
                    add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_ID", "");
                    add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_Section", "");
                    add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_Type", "");
                    add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_Answer", "");
                    add.Parameters["@SW_ID"].Value = saw.EntryID.ToString();
                    add.Parameters["@Checkbox_ID"].Value = CheckboxIDRecord.ToString();
                    add.Parameters["@Checkbox_Section"].Value = "SmokeDetectionReferral";
                    add.Parameters["@Checkbox_Type"].Value = "";
                    add.Parameters["@Checkbox_Answer"].Value = item.ToString();
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    add.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlcon.Close();
                }
```

As you can see what i have currently tried only inputs the ID for the first value selected in the Checkboxlist.

**The Aim**:

The aim is to have insert the value of the checkbox which is "name" and also the "id" of the each item.

**Research:**

I tried following this article to put the items into an array but ended up with a 'Array was out of bounds of the index' which led me to the second article.

[Pass items from checkboxlist to SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754667/pass-items-from-checkboxlist-to-sql-server-table)

[Index was out of bounds of array? c# forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124619/index-was-out-of-bounds-of-array-c-sharp-forms)

I would appreciate any guidance with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a dictionary for the items to be placed into the checkboxlist. This allows me to use the value within the checkbox items and then use the Key in the INSERT to the SQL DB.

```
Dictionary<string, string> referral = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

**On form load populate the checkboxlist with items from dictionary.**

```
private void Section3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id, name from SWApp_List_Equipment WHERE type = 'referral or signposting' ORDER BY order_no,name", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    referral.Add(dr["id"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString());
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> refs in referral)
            {
                box = new CheckBox();
                box.Text = refs.Value.ToString();
                actionsTakenCheckBoxList.Items.Add(box.Text);
                box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChange);
            } 
        }
```

**Insert values into table on Close Button of form.**

```
private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                    //summary
                    foreach (var item in actionsTakenCheckBoxList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList())
                    {

                        //ADD ACTIONS AND REFERRAL 
                        SqlCommand add = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SWApp_CheckboxAnswers (SW_ID, Checkbox_ID, Checkbox_Section, Checkbox_Type, Checkbox_Answer) VALUES(@SW_ID,@Checkbox_ID,@Checkbox_Section,@Checkbox_Type,@Checkbox_Answer) ");
                        add.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        add.Connection = sqlcon;
                        add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SW_ID", "");
                        add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_ID", "");
                        add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_Section", "");
                        add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_Type", "");
                        add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkbox_Answer", "");
                        add.Parameters["@SW_ID"].Value = entry.entryID.ToString();
                        var myKey = referral.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == item.ToString()).Key;
                        add.Parameters["@Checkbox_ID"].Value = myKey;
                        add.Parameters["@Checkbox_Section"].Value = "SmokeDetection";
                        add.Parameters["@Checkbox_Type"].Value = "Referral";
                        add.Parameters["@Checkbox_Answer"].Value = item.ToString();
                        sqlcon.Open();
                        add.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlcon.Close();

                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues, rather than attempting to rectify them here is a proposal for how to work this out.

The overall picture can be seen in my MSDN code sample on CheckedListBox and SQL-Server which includes an sql script to generate the datbase and data.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Working-with-CheckedListBox-3b765442?redir=0

Taken from the link above in Operations.cs, this method gets our data (next code block populates the CheckedListBox)

```
/// <summary>
/// Get all records to show in the CheckedListBox
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public DataTable GetAll()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn })
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, Description, Quantity, CheckedStatus FROM Products ---WHERE (Quantity > 0)";

            cn.Open();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        }
    }

    return dt;

}
```

Form code

```
/// <summary>
/// Load CheckedListBox from database table
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var ops = new Operations();

    // read data from database table
    var dt = ops.GetAll();

    int LastIndex = 0;

    /*
        * Here we iterate the rows in the DataTable while in
        * CoursesCodeSample I set the DataSource of the CheckedListBox
        * to the DataTable. The method shown here has always been the
        * way to go as many indicated that since the DataSource property
        * of the CheckedListBox is not documented it could go away, well
        * many years later it's still here so guess what, it's okay.
        */
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new CheckListBoxItem()
        {
            Description = row.Field<string>("Description"),
            PrimaryKey = row.Field<int>("id"),
            Quantity = row.Field<int>("Quantity"),
            IsDirty = false
        });

        LastIndex = checkedListBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(LastIndex, row.Field<bool>("CheckedStatus"));

    }

    checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck;

}
```

From Opertions.cs - insertion method

```
public void Insert(List<CheckListBoxItem> items)
{
    // optionally used for obtaining new primary key
    //int newIdentifier;

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn })
        {
            // uncomment ending select statement and use commented to get new primary key
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products " + 
                "([Description],Quantity,CheckedStatus) " + 
                "VALUES (@Description,@Quantity,@CheckedStatus); " + 
                "-- SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                { ParameterName = "@Description", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                { ParameterName = "@Quantity", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                { ParameterName = "@CheckedStatus", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit });
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                { ParameterName = "@CategoryIdentifier", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });


            cn.Open();

            foreach (CheckListBoxItem item in items)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = item.Description;
                cmd.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = item.Quantity;
                cmd.Parameters["@CheckedStatus"].Value = item.Checked;


                //newIdentifier = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if ((int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > -1)
                {
                    // inserted
                }
                else
                {
                    // failed
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is basic, the commented out code shows (if needed) how to get the new primary key.

Call the method above

```
private void iterateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = new List<CheckListBoxItem>();

    for (int index = 0; index < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; index++)
    {
        if (((CheckListBoxItem)checkedListBox1.Items[index]).IsDirty)
        {
            items.Add(new CheckListBoxItem()
            {
                PrimaryKey = ((CheckListBoxItem)checkedListBox1.Items[index]).PrimaryKey,
                Checked = checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(index),
                Description = ((CheckListBoxItem)checkedListBox1.Items[index]).Description
            });
        }
    }

    if (items.Count >0)
    {
        Ops.Insert(items);
    }
}
```

Finally the class used to populate the CheckedListBox

```
namespace CheckListBoxFromSQL_Server
{
    public class CheckListBoxItem
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Identifier for database table
        /// </summary>
        public int PrimaryKey;
        /// <summary>
        /// Display member for CheckedListBox and a field in the table
        /// </summary>
        public string Description;
        public int Quantity;
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates the checked state in the database table and for setting a Checked item in the CheckedListbox
        /// </summary>
        public bool Checked;
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to determine if a item changed after loaded in the CheckedListBox
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsDirty;
        public override string ToString() { return Description; }
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive, useful answer. I managed to get this working using a dictionary for the checkbox list items.